# Forcing angular to use jQuery over JQLite

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqlite

As per the angular DOCS
If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.

I am trying to force angular to use jQuery over JQLite by loading angular after jQuery. However angular.element still is a JQLite reference. Below is the code.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <button onClick="load()">load</button>
        <button onClick="check()">check</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        function load() {
            var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
            scriptElement.onload = function () {
                console.log("Successfully loaded script 2 using (onload).");
            };
            scriptElement.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js";
            document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
        }
        function check() {
            console.log(angular.element == jQuery) // false
        }
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Also after everything loads if I check `angular.element('div')` it gives jQlite error,

```
angular.js:3236 Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/jqLite/nosel
at angular.js:88
at Object.V [as element] (angular.js:3236)
at <anonymous>:1:9
```

which clearly means angular is pointing to jQlite and not jQuery.

I am doing as per the documentation to point angular to jQuery. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple as using the ngJq on the html element and passing in the window variable for jQuery. This will cause angular to override the use of jQlite

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app ng-jq="jQuery">
...
...
</html>
```